# how to upgrade pytorch in docker

Tags: docker, pytorch

When I'm trying to run a [github project](https://github.com/DecaYale/RNNPose/tree/main), an error appears

```
    NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU with CUDA capability sm_86 is not compatible with the current PyTorch installation.
The current PyTorch install supports CUDA capabilities sm_37 sm_50 sm_60 sm_61 sm_70 sm_75 compute_37.
If you want to use the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU GPU with PyTorch, please check the instructions at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
```

it seems like I need a pytorch version that can run sm_86, I've tried changing the pytorch version in freeze.yml but package conflict appears, how do I upgrade or reinstall pytorch, down below are my Dockerfile and freeze.yml

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04

RUN apt-key del 7fa2af80
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list

# Dependencies for glvnd and X11.
RUN apt-get update 
RUN  apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
    libglvnd0 \
    libgl1 \
    libglx0 \
    libegl1 \
    libxext6 \
    libx11-6 \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Env vars for the nvidia-container-runtime.
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES graphics,utility,compute

#env vars for cuda
ENV CUDA_HOME /usr/local/cuda

#install miniconda
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && \
    apt-get install -y wget bzip2 ca-certificates curl git && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget --quiet https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda3 && \
    rm ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda clean -tipsy && \
    ln -s /opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda deactivate && conda activate py37" >> ~/.bashrc

#https://blog.csdn.net/Mao_Jonah/article/details/89502380
COPY freeze.yml freeze.yml
RUN /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda env create -n py37 -f freeze.yml

# WORKDIR /tmp/
# COPY config.jupyter.tar config.jupyter.tar
# RUN tar -xvf config.jupyter.tar -C /root/

#other pkgs
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
  cmake build-essential vim xvfb unzip tmux psmisc  \
  libx11-dev libassimp-dev \
  mesa-common-dev freeglut3-dev \
  rsync \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#create some directories
RUN mkdir -p /home/RNNPose

EXPOSE 8887 8888 8889 10000 10001 10002 
WORKDIR /tmp/unique_for_apex
```

freeze.yml

```
name: py37_tmp
channels:
  - pytorch
  - pytorch3d
  - open3d-admin
  - bottler
  - iopath
  - fvcore
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pytorch3d=0.5.0
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
  - anyio=2.2.0=py37h06a4308_1
  - argon2-cffi=20.1.0=py37h27cfd23_1
  - async_generator=1.10=py37h28b3542_0
  - attrs=21.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - babel=2.9.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=3.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py37h27cfd23_1003
  - ca-certificates=2021.5.30=ha878542_0
  - certifi=2021.5.30=py37h89c1867_0
  - cffi=1.14.5=py37h261ae71_0
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - cryptography=3.4.7=py37hd23ed53_0
  - cudatoolkit=10.2.89=h8f6ccaa_8
  - cycler=0.10.0=py37_0
  - dbus=1.13.18=hb2f20db_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - entrypoints=0.3=py37_0
  - expat=2.4.1=h2531618_2
  - fontconfig=2.13.1=h6c09931_0
  - freetype=2.10.4=h5ab3b9f_0
  - fvcore=0.1.5.post20210825=py37
  - glib=2.68.2=h36276a3_0
  - gst-plugins-base=1.14.0=h8213a91_2
  - gstreamer=1.14.0=h28cd5cc_2
  - icu=58.2=he6710b0_3
  - idna=3.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - importlib-metadata=3.10.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - importlib_metadata=3.10.0=hd3eb1b0_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.2.0=h06a4308_610
  - iopath=0.1.9=py37
  - ipykernel=5.3.4=py37h5ca1d4c_0
  - ipython=7.22.0=py37hb070fc8_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - ipywidgets=7.6.3=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - jedi=0.17.0=py37_0
  - jinja2=3.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - joblib=1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - json5=0.9.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jsonschema=3.2.0=py_2
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py37h89c1867_6
  - jupyter_client=6.1.12=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jupyter_console=6.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_core=4.7.1=py37h06a4308_0
  - jupyter_server=1.4.1=py37h06a4308_0
  - jupyterlab=3.0.16=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=py_0
  - jupyterlab_server=2.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - kiwisolver=1.3.1=py37h2531618_0
  - kornia=0.5.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - lcms2=2.12=h3be6417_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h7274673_9
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libgfortran-ng=7.5.0=ha8ba4b0_17
  - libgfortran4=7.5.0=ha8ba4b0_17
  - libgomp=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h7b6447c_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.3.0=hd4cf53a_17
  - libtiff=4.2.0=h85742a9_0
  - libuuid=1.0.3=h1bed415_2
  - libuv=1.40.0=h7b6447c_0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.0=h27cfd23_0
  - libxcb=1.14=h7b6447c_0
  - libxml2=2.9.10=hb55368b_3
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h2531618_0
  - markupsafe=2.0.1=py37h27cfd23_0
  - matplotlib=3.3.4=py37h06a4308_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.3.4=py37h62a2d02_0
  - mistune=0.8.4=py37h14c3975_1001
  - mkl=2021.2.0=h06a4308_296
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py37h27cfd23_1
  - mkl_fft=1.3.0=py37h42c9631_2
  - mkl_random=1.2.1=py37ha9443f7_2
  - nbclassic=0.2.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - nbclient=0.5.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - nbconvert=6.0.7=py37_0
  - nbformat=5.1.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - ninja=1.10.2=hff7bd54_1
  - notebook=6.4.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - numpy=1.20.2=py37h2d18471_0
  - numpy-base=1.20.2=py37hfae3a4d_0
  - nvidiacub=1.10.0=0
  - olefile=0.46=py37_0
  - open3d=0.13.0=py37_0
  - openssl=1.1.1k=h7f98852_0
  - packaging=20.9=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pandas=1.2.4=py37h2531618_0
  - pandoc=2.12=h06a4308_0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.3=py37h06a4308_1
  - parso=0.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pcre=8.44=he6710b0_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - pillow=8.2.0=py37he98fc37_0
  - pip=21.1.2=py37h06a4308_0
  - plyfile=0.7.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - portalocker=2.3.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - prometheus_client=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.17=pyh06a4308_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.17=hd3eb1b0_0
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - pycparser=2.20=py_2
  - pygments=2.9.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyopenssl=20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py37h05f1152_2
  - pyrsistent=0.17.3=py37h7b6447c_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py37_1
  - python=3.7.10=h12debd9_4
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python_abi=3.7=1_cp37m
  - pytorch=1.7.1=py3.7_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0
  - pytz=2021.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyzmq=20.0.0=py37h2531618_1
  - qt=5.9.7=h5867ecd_1
  - qtconsole=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qtpy=1.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - readline=8.1=h27cfd23_0
  - requests=2.26.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - scikit-learn=0.24.2=py37ha9443f7_0
  - scipy=1.6.2=py37had2a1c9_1
  - send2trash=1.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - setuptools=52.0.0=py37h06a4308_0
  - sip=4.19.8=py37hf484d3e_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sniffio=1.2.0=py37h06a4308_1
  - sqlite=3.35.4=hdfb4753_0
  - tabulate=0.8.9=py37h06a4308_0
  - terminado=0.9.4=py37h06a4308_0
  - testpath=0.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - threadpoolctl=2.1.0=pyh5ca1d4c_0
  - tk=8.6.10=hbc83047_0
  - torchvision=0.8.2=py37_cu102
  - tornado=6.1=py37h27cfd23_0
  - traitlets=5.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - typing_extensions=3.7.4.3=pyha847dfd_0
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=py_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py37_1
  - wheel=0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.5.1=py37_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - yacs=0.1.6=py_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - zeromq=4.3.4=h2531618_0
  - zipp=3.4.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.4.9=haebb681_0
  - pip:
    - absl-py==0.13.0
    - addict==2.4.0
    - anykeystore==0.2
    - cachetools==4.2.2
    - cryptacular==1.5.5
    - cython==0.29.24
    - decorator==4.4.2
    - easydict==1.9
    - einops==0.3.0
    - fire==0.4.0
    - flow-vis==0.1
    - freetype-py==2.2.0
    - future==0.18.2
    - glumpy==1.2.0
    - google-auth==1.31.0
    - google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.4
    - greenlet==1.1.0
    - grpcio==1.38.0
    - hupper==1.10.3
    - imageio==2.9.0
    - llvmlite==0.36.0
    - loguru==0.5.3
    - markdown==3.3.4
    - networkx==2.5.1
    - numba==0.53.1
    - numpy-quaternion==2021.6.9.13.34.11
    - oauthlib==3.1.1
    - opencv-python==4.5.2.54
    - pastedeploy==2.1.1
    - pbkdf2==1.3
    - plaster==1.0
    - plaster-pastedeploy==0.7
    - protobuf==3.17.3
    - pyasn1==0.4.8
    - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
    - pyassimp==4.1.3
    - pyglet==1.5.17
    - pyopengl==3.1.5
    - pyopengl-accelerate==3.1.5
    - pyramid==2.0
    - pyramid-mailer==0.15.1
    - python3-openid==3.2.0
    - pywavelets==1.1.1
    - pyyaml==5.4.1
    - repoze-sendmail==4.4.1
    - requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
    - rsa==4.7.2
    - scikit-image==0.18.1
    - sqlalchemy==1.4.18
    - tensorboard==2.5.0
    - tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
    - tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
    - tensorboardx==2.2
    - termcolor==1.1.0
    - tifffile==2021.6.14
    - tqdm==4.61.1
    - transaction==3.0.1
    - transforms3d==0.3.1
    - translationstring==1.4
    - triangle==20200424
    - urllib3==1.26.5
    - velruse==1.1.1
    - venusian==3.0.0
    - vispy==0.6.6
    - webob==1.8.7
    - werkzeug==2.0.1
    - zope-deprecation==4.4.0
    - zope-interface==5.4.0
    - mmcv 
prefix: /opt/miniconda3/envs/py37_tmp
```

I installed apex manually afer docker run.

```
git clone https://github.com/ptrblck/apex.git
cd apex
git checkout apex_no_distributed
pip install -v --no-cache-dir ./
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your starting docker line and your CUDA version. You need CUDA 11.1 or higher for that card, not 10.2.

You will have to write a more recent Dockerfile for that GPU, or run it on another machine. Here's a possible start, given that the repo you linked uses Pytorch 1.7.1:

https://github.com/anibali/docker-pytorch/blob/master/dockerfiles/1.7.0-cuda11.0-ubuntu20.04/Dockerfile

**EDIT**: you might get away just by editing your yml file. For sure you have to switch to cuda 11, instead of 10.2.

If you check PyTorch docs, you can see for v1.7.1

> conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2
> cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch

https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Currently, you have e.g.
`cudatoolkit=10.2.89=h8f6ccaa_8`

Note that the last `=h8f6ccaa_8` is architecture dependent (linux, win, mac) and you don't have to specify it.

Comment: The problem is whenever I edit the package version either from dockerfile(I have to use FROM nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-base-ubuntu20.04 instead of cuda:11.0 cuz the image was removed) or freeze.yml, Error code like package conflict or not found appears everywhere. Is there any list or something I can check for the version?